# Finding all possible connections between two disjoint hierarchical trees

Tags: data-structures, tree, graph-theory, hierarchical-data, traversal

I am looking for the best data structure to store two hierarchical trees, where my aim is to find whether all the possible connections between these two trees are covered.

I will describe my problem in detail here  -
I have two trees (referred to as `first_tree` and `second_tree` henceforth) like the following. The root of the tree is the name of the state -like Florida, California. The children of the root are its cities, and their children can be its sub regions.

Now I want to assign a property(road connectivity between two subregions) to each of the leaf node pairs of these trees. Basically I have a function f: (leaf_node_first_tree x leaf_node_second_tree) --> R.

Since these number of these leaf node pairs can become huge to specify individually, and also sometimes I do not have the information for each leaf node pair, I want to generalize this property from the information present at the parent's level.

So I create a list of assignment rules, where the order of the rules matter.

```
1. from State=Florida, to State = California , assign value =1
2. from city = Miami , to city = Sacramento , assign value =2
3. from sub_region = West Palm Beach , to sub_region = east_sacramento, assign value =3
```

Assume that all the node names - States, cities, sub-regions are unique, that they can be easily specified by these rules.
These rules assign the property to node pairs in the following way -

1. It checks all the leaf node descendants of the first node in the`first tree` , lets say `leaf_node_set1`, and of the second node in the `second tree`, lets say `leaf_node_set2`. And assigns the value specified by the rule to each element of the cartesian product of two leaf nodes set (`leaf_node_set1 x leaf_note_set2`).
2. Later rules can overwrite the property value for a leaf_node_pair.

Since in this case, I am assigning a rule at the root node of both the tree, so it is guaranteed that I will have a property for each of the leaf node pair. But this may not be the case for any general set of rules.

So I am looking for a data structure which can store these two trees, along with the connections between any two nodes of this tree. (Storing the individual trees is trivial with any tree based data structure). The design of the data structure should permit the efficient calculation of the following  -

1. Given a set of these assignment rules, an efficient function which can tell whether I have covered all the node pairs or not.
2. Given a set of these rules, and a leaf node pair, what is the assignment value for that pair?

I have looked at the tree based data structures but they are mostly for just one tree. For this case, I need to do tree traversal for both the trees, and keep their children and leaf node descendants in mind, while assigning the properties.

EDIT :
I am adding a concrete example for more clarity, if it helps.
Let's say the first tree is the following (each node is identified by the text shown on the node) -
[image: First Hierarchical tree]
, and the second tree is the following  -
[image]

I would like to assign some property to each of 16 pair of leaf node elements - [(F1,C1),(F1,C2),(F1,C3),(F1,C4),......, (F4,C3), (F4,C4)]

I assign these leaf node pairs some values, based on some set of rules.
An example set of rule is the following -

```
1. (Florida, California) -> 10
2. (Miami,Sacramento) -> 12
3. (F2,C2) -> 15
```

If we just take the first rule, the leaf nodes associated with the node "Florida" are [F1,F2,F3,F4] , and leaf nodes associated with the node "California" are [C1,C2,C3,C4] , so their cross product, which means all the 16 leaf node pairs gets assigned the value of 10.
Then we apply the second rule, the leaf node pairs corresponding to this rule are the cross product of [F1,F2] and [C1,C2]. Hence the  value of the leaf node pairs [(F1,C1),(F1,C2),(F2,C1),(F2,C2)] get updated to 12.
Then we apply the third rule, and the value of pair, (F2,C2) gets updated to 15.  So after applying these rules, I have [(F1,C1),(F1,C2),(F2,C1)] pairs having value 12, [(F2,C2]) having value 15, and the rest having the value 10.

In case the set of our rules was only following -

```
1. (F2,C2) -> 15
2. (Miami, Sacremento) -> 12
```

We will have for pairs [(F1,C1), (F1,C2) , (F2,C1) , (F2,C2)] , the value of 12 and all the rest pairs will have an unassigned value/none. The value for the pair (F2,C2) will be overwritten by the second rule, since it comes later in the list.
I want to organize my data such that I can answer the two queries efficiently -

1. For any pair (Fi, Ci), what is the value associated with it.
2. Are there pair of leaf nodes, with non null values.

Comment: Do you intend to calculate the values for leaf pairs once, then optimize storing these values so that later queries are as fast as possible?  Do you care about the amount of memory used?

Answer (score 0):

> For any pair (Fi, Ci), what is the value associated with it.

To optimize the speed of this query, without regard to memory usage: Use a hash function and store the values in a vector.  To lookup a particular value then requires:

- Calculate the hash for the pair requested pair
- Lookup the value in the vector using the hash value as the vector index.

The lookup is extremely fast, so you need to focus on an efficiently calculated hash.

- Calculate ( or estimate ) the maximum count of Ci in any any Fi. Call the count X
- Hash function ( index in array )

  H = Fi * X * 2 + Ci

---

> Are there pair of leaf nodes, with non null values.

I do not understand this query.  But perhaps this will serve:

- Build the vector of values indexed by a hash function as described in first part of answer
- Iterate over the vector, until you find a non null value

---

This will run fast - I do not believe anything could be faster.  However, it is not very efficient at usining memory - especially if the count of Cs in F varies greatly ( because the vector will have many empty slots ).  If this is a concern you will want to consider other hash functions that run a bit more slowly but are more memory efficient. )